# Puts integer from rand -Ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello I am new to Ruby.

I am trying to return a random dice roll. I just want the result to be puts to screen with a string.

Please see code.

```
roll = Array.new(1) { rand(1..12) }

if roll > 7 
  puts "  'The fates are in your favour' "
elsif roll <= 7 and roll!=0
  puts "   'The fates are in my favour' "
end
```

Your help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`Array.new(1) { rand(1..12) }` created a 1-element array containing a random number between 1 and 12. But you apparently expect `roll` to be an integer (`if roll > 7`), so you should remove the array part:

```
roll = rand(1..12)
```

The `elsif` contains an `and` which is a control-flow operator. You want `&&`:

```
elsif roll <= 7 && roll != 0
```

However, since `roll` is a number between 1 and 12, it cannot become `0`. It can be simplified to:

```
elsif roll <= 7
```

Or, if there are no other options, simply

```
else
```

The whole code:

```
roll = rand(1..12)

if roll > 7
  puts "  'The fates are in your favour'"
else
  puts "  'The fates are in my favour'"
end
```

Comment: @LukePatch can you give an example – how should the string / output look like?

Comment: Luke, if you are rolling two dice and wish to display the sum, you want `roll = rand(1..6) + rand(1..6)`. That's of course not the same as `roll = rand(2..12)`, as the probability of rolling a `7` is `1/6` whereas the probability of rolling snake-eyes is `1/36`.